# Handlebars.js doesn't handle unicode as JSON's key?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, cjk, mustache

I'am using handlebars.js and JSON data to fill my HTML. My test fail if I call a JSON key which is a CJK unicode character. **Is there any workaround to successfully process (CJK) unicode keys with handlebars.js ?**

This works [1]:

```
var source2   = '<p>{{blatitle}}<br />{{bla.zht}}} / {{bla.pyn}} / {{bla.dfn}}</p>';
var template = Handlebars.compile(source2);
var html  = template(jsonDictSample);
$('#container2')
  .append(html);
```

This doesn't works (case duplication, only change key 'bla' into unicode '**口**' as key) [1]:

```
var source3   = '<p>{{title}}<br />{{口.zht}} / {{口.pyn}} / {{口.dfn}}</p>';
var template = Handlebars.compile(source3);
var html  = template(jsonDictSample);
$('#container3')
  .append(html);
```

**Note1:** I know I can convert to and use "u53E3" for the unicode character "口", but I want to keep my JSON with CJK unicode characters such "口".

**Note2 - Mustache works:** CJK unicode keys works with Mustache.js [2], so it's not JSON issue, but an handlebars.js issue. Since I need advanced function, I am still looking for a Handlebars solution.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/YqhKG/ -- handlebar test: fail.
[2]: note -- mustache.js test: works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be out of luck or at least in an unpleasant place. If you look at the [Handlebars source](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/src/handlebars.l), you'll see regexes like `[a-zA-Z]+` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_$-]+/[=}\s\/.]` that drive the parsing, I suspect that the rather limited `a-zA-Z` components are behind your trouble.

Comment: If someone know how to fix & push an unicode compliant bug fix, it may help.
Note: I moved back to Mustache.js.

Comment: [Bug reported](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/433)

Comment: [Bug fixed](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/433). Need to wait a bit before the fix spread around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download **[Handlebars.js v.1.0.11](https://raw.github.com/alejandrogarciaiglesias/handlebars.js/master/lib/handlebars.js) or above.**

---

The github bug report was recently answered. The fix was to replace the alpha-numeric regex:

[a-zA-Z0-9_$:-]

into unicode complient regex:

[^\s!"#%-,./;->@[-\^`{-~]

Done [on github by kpdecker](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/commit/c1020a01309723b00ef21525d7f8093efb4d0d93.)